# Difference between ReactDOM.render() callback and onComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a single top-level state which is updated on every frame tick, as long as the previous render is finished. If the renderer is still busy, then it tries to pass in the updated state on the next tick.

The idiomatic way to detect when rendering is complete in React, would be to set a flag on `componentDidUpdate`. However, this requires keeping the state wrapped in another top-level class-based component, which isn't necessary in my case.

I'd prefer to just pass that top-level state (i.e. element tree) directly to `ReactDOM.render()` and use the callback to indicate that rendering is done (note: in this setup I'm passing the same target/mount point on each call so React can do its diffing thing). However, I'm not entirely sure that this is what the callback is intended for.

**Will the callback in `ReactDOM.render()` fire only after the entire tree has finished rendering, both on the first render and subsequent ones?**

Comment: I cannot answer your question about `ReactDOM.render()` but I can tell you that `componentDidUpdate` will only fire when all its children have finished rendering. Why wouldn't you keep the state in the same component that has the `componentDidUpdate`, I don't understand.

Comment: It's a pure functional component that generates the element tree on tick. It's called externally, not via an internal tick handler

Comment: In other words, in my current setup there are no lifecycle hooks anywhere, not even on the top level